# Ant Design: how to select date only for certain month in ant calendar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm using antD 3.x version with react.

The issue:

When i select date eg septemper 15, the circle shows like selected. It's okay, but...

[selected september 15][1]

When i choose next or previous month like august or november, date shows like selected too

[still selected september 15][2]

So how should i do to select only certain date of certain month?

Here's the doc and examples looks simmilar to my problem: https://3x.ant.design/components/calendar/

Also even when i set date like

````
        className="account-calendar__right-calendar"
        value={moment(['2020', '08', '15'])}
        onSelect={(value) => changeField('selectedDay', value)}
        fullscreen={false}
        dateFullCellRender={cell => this.calendarCells(cell)}
        headerRender={({value}) => this.calendarHeader(value, i)}
      />;```

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qNwy.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/25LLi.png
````